# unresolved identifier errors in Xcode 8 and Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, code-translation

I'm trying to translate a project from Swift 2 to 3, and I'm facing various problems.

First of all I've used XCode 8 built-in migration tool for automatically converting the code, but after the conversion the IDE shows me a lot of errors, for example when I changed the variable types from NSURL to URL I get the error "unresolved identifier 'URL' ", and the same happens to other types such as Date, Bundle, DispatchQueque.. (I've imported Foundation)

Other types of errors are for example " UIImagePickerControllerSourceType has no member 'camera' ", but checking on the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollersourcetype) it seems to be correct.

Here there is a snippet of code:

```
func createFileUrl() -> URL {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"

        let fileName: String = dateFormatter.string(from: Date()) + (".m4a")
        let filePath: String = getCacheDirectory() + ("/\(fileName)")

        self.recordedAudioUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
        return self.recordedAudioUrl
    }
```

The errors here are unresolved identifiers: URL, Date, DateFormatter.

Another big problem is that Xcode is highlighting the error in the previous line of code and when I change the code (also for example just deleting the line) the error doesn't disappear.

Does someone had similar problems? I'm not familiar with Swift but it seems that my Xcode is not working properly.

EDIT: I found a solution, my code is auto-generated by a modeling tool in eclipse, I just added SWIFT_VERSION = 3.0 in the build settings and now everything goes fine

Comment: Are you sure you have updated to Swift 3 (not Swift 2.3)? Try to clean the project (⇧⌘K)

Comment: close Xcode, reopen.

Comment: I tried to reopen many times nothing changed. I've updated to swift 3, cleaning the project says: clean failed

Comment: Don't stick to this line of code if you're stuck and know that this is already correct... Fix the other error since it sometimes prevents the xcode from verifying other line of codes. so you better fix the other error and rerun again.

Answer (score 0):

if you have many errors, possibly you have missed 1 } curly brackets as I tried your code and there is no problems with the Date, URL and DateFormatter.

try to run your project, reopen, clean, and even restart your mac.